# How to set URL in Store's proxy?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

My code has a bug, but I cann't figure out what is wrong.
I try to set new url in the Store when leaf item of NestedList is tapped.
Here is my store:

```
Ext.define('Application.store.DetailStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    model: 'Application.model.DetailModel',
    autoLoad :true,
    sorters: 'title',
    grouper : function(record) {
        return record.get('title')[0];
        },

   proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url : '/data/data1.php',
   reader: {
   type: 'json',
  rootProperty:'recipes'}
         } 
}
```

});

And this is my listener of leafitemtap in NestedList:

```
onLeafItemTap: function(nestedList, list, index, node, record, e) {
    filter = record.get('text');
    var detailCard = nestedList.getDetailCard();       
    Ext.getStore('Application.store.DetailStore').getProxy().setUrl('/data/data2.php');
    Ext.getStore('Application.store.DetailStore').load()
}
```

After this I cann't tap on leaf item and detail card doesn't show.
does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I used the getMain method to push the detailCard on top of the list when the leaf item is tapped and the store is loaded. I am also assuming you are defining the leafitemtap logic in your controller using getMain as a ref.

You can also use the storeId instead of "Application.store.DetailStore"

```
        Ext.getStore('Application.store.DetailStore').setProxy({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/data/data2.php'
    }).load({
        callback: function(records, operations, success) {
            if (success = true) {
                this.getMain().push({
                    xtype: 'detailsCard',
                    data: record.getData()
                })
            } else {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Something went wrong!', Ext.emptyFn);
            }
        },
        scope: this
    });
```

Comment: Reading back over the question if all you want to do is set and load the store just write: Ext.getStore('Application.store.DetailStore').setProxy({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/data/data2.php'}).load()
instead of using getProxy and setUrl

Comment: thank you for reply! but it doesn't help,I still can't tap on leaf item. I tested to delete some parts of code, it stops work when I wrote something after Ext.getStore('Application.store.DetailStore')

Comment: Can you post the NestedList view, model, and the JSON you are fetching from the store?

Comment: sorry for bothering you, I understand that using different url isn't right, that I must filter my Store. Thank for your time!